# How to add new line (vbCrLf) in a string, by search of a short string (<br/>)?

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm working with a function which get a string data from a database. I need to translate the `<br/>` into `vbCrLf`, or vice versa when I need to store the data. I wrote this function, but the return string have no changes:

```
Private Function ReemplazarNuevaLinea(ByRef strTexto As String) As String
    If strTexto.Contains("<br/>") Then
        strTexto.Replace("<br/>", vbCrLf)
    Else
        strTexto.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br/>")
    End If
    Return strTexto
End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.Net Replace not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282903/vb-net-replace-not-working)

Comment: Sorry, that resolved my problem: I need a variable to store the replaced string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Private Function ReemplazarNuevaLinea(ByRef strTexto As String) As String
If strTexto.Contains("<br/>") Then
  strTexto =  strTexto.Replace("<br/>", vbCrLf)
Else
  strTexto =  strTexto.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br/>")
End If
Return strTexto
End Function
```

Explanation: The replace function does not alter the string itself.  You have to either assign the value to a new string, or to the same string.

Comment: Be aware that this Replace() is case-sensitive, which should be OK in your case but not every.

Comment: Also as a side note too, if there's places where there's a space in between the br and the /, you might also want to do a replace on that as well.  If this never happens, then this should work fine as is.  I can't speak for your solution, but I know in code that I've worked with in the past, it's always been kind of hit or miss if the space exists between br and the / or not.  Just something extra to keep in mind.

Comment: @user2366842 Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function ReemplazarNuevaLinea(ByRef strTexto As String) As String
    If strTexto.Contains("<br/>") Then
        Return strTexto.Replace("<br/>", vbCrLf)
    Else
        Return strTexto.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br/>")
    End If
End Function
```